# Dock Folder Stack - I want ascending order

Tags: macos, dock

Before I upgraded to OS X Lion, when I click a stack, it would show the very top. Now, it shows the very bottom of the menu meaning you would see the "Open in Finder" option after you click it. Now, I sorted my download folder by "Date Added" and its very annoying that I am seeing the oldest files first rather than the newest ones. I would have to scroll all the way to the top to access the new files. How can I have the newer files be shown first aka ascending order?

Comment: I submitted this as a bug - RADAR ID 9982917

Comment: I'm also running 10.7.2 and the same issue exists. I'll update (when I hear back) if this is a known issue.

Comment: Re http://secrets.blacktree.com/?search=stack if you show the Recent Applications stack as a list, how is it ordered? Consider adding detail to the question.

Comment: Workaround: Press the Home button when you open it to scroll to the top.

Answer (score 4):

In my Downloads stack I don't have this problem. The ordering is correct, i.e. latest download appears at the bottom.

The settings which achieve this are:

Sort by: **Date Added**

Display as: **Stack**

View content as: **Fan**

I hope these settings work for you too.

Comment: When I switch to List view I have exactly the problem you mention, so this is clearly a Lion bug. Hopefully fixed in 10.7.1. For the short term, Fan is a good work around.

Comment: I reproduced you problem on Mountain Lion 10.8.3, never noticed the problem because I always use fan view.

Comment: I observe that "Date Added" is different from "Date Created".  I also observe that "Grid"  mode has a different sort order than "Fan" mode.  Highly unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

My downloads folder is a stack with latest downloads appearing at the top without me having to move the slider. When I 'right' click the downloads folder icon in the dock, a contextual menu appears.

Comment: You have yours at automatic, but I use list because sometimes the filenames are long and its more convenient for me to see it all in one go.

Comment: Too bad we can't get List to work in descending order. Come on Apple!

Answer (score 2):

I had mine set to List as well and noticed the problem right away after upgrade (my Downloads folder is huge).

I think this is a bug. The grid view has the correct initial position (at the top of the reverse chronological ordering)

I suspect we'll need to switch to grid view until a patch comes along. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock use-new-list-stack -bool YES
```

This gives you another type of List view that always starts at the top of the list with the latest files. You can scroll down for earlier files.

Comment: I think he's looking for the reverse, latest files at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I see this when I have the "list" setting.  A work around is to press control-commnd-up arrow and this will bring you to the top of the list.