# How do I get my folder list from the dock to start at the TOP of the folder rather the bottom, when organized by date?

Tags: macos, dock

I have a frequently used folder set up in my dock to display as a list, organized by date modified.

The problem here is that I have several hundred items in that folder, and most frequently I need to access the ones that are most recently modified, but I always have to scroll to the top of my long list, since Apple defaults to showing the *oldest* modified (i.e. the bottom of the list) by default. How does this make any sense for the user?

Any way to change this display, so I can avoid having to move upward through 800 files and folders every time I click on the list? I changed it to display as a stack and the same thing is happening. I also tried to change the sorting to date added, and date created, only to have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense if you think about it from a Finder perspective...when you click on Date Modified in Finder, you generally want the newest items at the top of the list.

That said, it doesn't make sense when the list in this case opens from the bottom (at least, not without some way to sort the opposite way). I wasn't able to find a way around this, but there are two work-arounds:

- Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> to jump up a page at a time
- Use the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to jump straight to the top of the list (similarly, <kbd>End</kbd> jumps back to the bottom)

On a Mac keyboard without <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> keys, the combination <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> stands in for <kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> stands in for <kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! The home button solution is a good workaround for when I'm using my external keyboard and monitor, since I'm using a MacBook Pro. Any ideas on how I can fake the home button or use some other single button press to get to the top using my laptop keyboard?

Comment: @OohMamma See updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again! I also found this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20451/dock-folder-stack-i-want-ascending-order?rq=1 so I can also use a fan, which is not ideal, but it's another workaround.